# what does -crf mean in ffmpeg resize video file command?

Tags: ffmpeg

Could someone explain what `-crf` means in the following command:

> `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 65 -b:v 1M -c:a aac output.mp4`

What does `-crf` stand for?

Comment: Constant Rate Factor, guide here: https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html

Comment: As for your command you can only use one rate control method at a time, so `-crf` and `-b:v` are mutually exclusive. This means that one of these is going to be ignored. Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CRF** (Constant Rate Factor) is the default quality setting for the `x264 and x265` encoders. You can set the values between `0 and 51`, where :

1. lower values would result in better quality, at the expense of higher file sizes.
2. Higher values mean more compression, but at some point, you will notice the quality degradation.

You can also read about **[the Quantization Parameter](https://slhck.info/video/2017/03/01/rate-control.html)** which controls the amount of compression for every Macroblock in a frame

Comment: According to ffmpeg documentation, about codec h264, CRF 18 is considered lossless to human eyes without using analysis tool. It would be equivalent to a 512kbps mp3, which many audio engineers cannot distinguish from a flac losless in a hearing test without analysis tools.