# Overlaying 2 videos using FFMPEG in Android Giving Low Resolution Video Output

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm overlaying 2 videos using below command
This command works perfectly but returns Low resolution Video output any change to this command which make my video resolution better ...!!?

```
    "-i", FirstVideo, "-f","lavfi","-i","movie=" + SeconedVideo+ 
    
":loop=200,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB","-filter_complex",             
    
"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=1[u];[b][u]overlay=1:1:shortest=1", OutputFilePath
```

Comment: Add "-crf 28" in your command.

have look at this https://superuser.com/questions/677576/what-is-crf-used-for-in-ffmpeg#:~:text=The%20crf%20flag%20ensures%20a,Encode%2FVP9%20for%20more%20information. 

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985523/what-does-crf-mean-in-ffmpeg-resize-video-file-command

Comment: @pratikvekariya please tell me where to add -crf 28 exactly in command

Comment: add after filter_complex command ends like filter command ends at ".....shortest=1" after this "-crf","28". this way.